# Why Drupal doesn't use special Memory Limit (ini_set) in Cache Clearing Script?

Tags: caching

In Drupal 7, i have found that `CLEAR CACHE` (on the Web Panel) is using extreme high Memory resource. Giant projects like mine, needs over 350MB to that process.

- Then i set `400MB` inside `php.ini`

So as far as i have investigated, i have found that having high memory limit (Globally) is totally the `damage` to the overall Performance **because every single script is using that limit in memory**.

- Then i found, we can use separate/runtime setting as `ini_set('memory_limit',____)` only for the specific scripts.

So my question here is:

- Why Drupal by default is `NOT HAVING` this `ini_set('memory_limit',____)` separately in Cache Clearing Script (as hardcoded or in Panel Setting, etc) ?

Comment: The PHP memory limit is just that - a _limit_. The actual amount used by any particular PHP script depends on what the code does. So for example the memory used to return a page from the page cache on a bare-bones Drupal installation will be different to that required to create the permissions matrix screen on a site with a large number of modules and roles.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. You are not going to the point.

Comment: memory_limit is a safety precaution to prevent PHP from crashing a server due to bad code.  PHP will only increase memory when it needs it.  If you watch a site under heavy load with top, you can see how much memory each httpd process is taking, and most times it isn't close to memory_limit.  You do need to be careful, though, as httpd will keep memory it allocates.  So, if one request hogs memory, then subsequent requests will, too.  Playing with MaxRequestsPerChild and MaxMemFree can help with this.

Comment: How much memory does an average Drupal page load consume?  Also, are you using APC?  If so, can you please add your APC cache values?

Answer (score 4):

> Why Drupal by default is NOT HAVING this ini_set('memory_limit',*_*_) separately in Cache Clearing Script (as hardcoded or in Panel Setting, etc) ?

Quite simply because Drupal doesn't know if your website has permission to change that value at runtime, so it can't be used as a generic solution. Most shared hosts won't allow you to set your own site's memory limit for example, it's locked down to a server-wide default.

As Andy already said, giving PHP a *limit* of 400MB **does not mean that every single PHP script will use 400MB**. It's a limit, PHP won't go above it, but it won't necessarily use all of it either.

Comment: You are wrong. Learn here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858457/is-the-more-the-better-for-php-memory-limit

Comment: No I'm not wrong, you've misunderstood the point of this and the answer to your other question. I'll make the most pertinent point again... **giving PHP a limit of 400MB does not mean that every single PHP script will use 400MB.**

Comment: @4lvin I can't find anything in that Topic which goes against what Clive said. What exactly is he wrong about?

Comment: `memory_limit` in `php.ini` makes every php scripts taking to that limit. `memory_limit = 50MB` will make 20x php scripts to eat `1GB` of system memory. That is the major reason why Drupal is so slow around because of Drupal is pulling up so many separate Child Scripts in one page load. Thats why Drupal needs so much Caching Techniques.

Comment: @4lvin No that's incorrect. It's a ***LIMIT*** (see the definition of the word [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/limit)). If a script does not need 50MB, it will not take up 50MB, simple as that.

Comment: @Clive, i like your last comment.

Comment: @4lvin have a look at the [`memory_limit` definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) to understand it better. `This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate.`